# Media query hover: none always activated

Tags: sass, hover, media-queries

This probably get flagged as duplicate but I went through all questions and answers and did not find my very simple question answered.
I have this sass for links:

```
@base-color: black
:root
  color: $base-color
a
  color: inherit
  text-decoration: none

  @media (hover: none)
    border-bottom: 2px solid $base-color
  &:hover
    border-bottom: 2px solid $base-color
```

Simply enough I want a border-bottom on hover or if no hover is available to show the border-bottom unconditionally. The effect of the above code is an unconditional display of the border on touch and none touch displays.

What can I do to get the required behaviour?

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/theking2/pen/eYjWaKZ)
For me the link always has a border-bottom.

EDIT: add a codepen:

Comment: This works as intended here. Desktop browsers only show the border on hover, and mobile devices show the border permanently.

Comment: @EmSixTeen interesting. I created the codepen and on Chromium Edge, Chrome, Firefox I have a permanent border.

Comment: I have to amend that. Apparently a plugin prevented the proper working of `@media(hover)` The code above works on a vanila firefox and edge